# No output in Dash callback - multiple input and multiple outputs

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I am facing an issue when I am trying to display text outputs in my Dash application. I am working with multiple inputs and multiple outputs.

```py
# Define the output row where the forecast will be displayed
output_row = dbc.Container([
    html.Center(html.U(html.H4("Results"))), 
    html.Br(), 
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            html.H5("Result of the operation:"),
            html.Output(id='operation-result')
        ]), 
        dbc.Col([
            html.H5("Forecasted ACR Value:"),
            html.Output(id='acr-forecast')
        ])
    ])
])

# Define the app layout
def ACR_Prediction():
    layout = html.Div([
        nav,
        header,
        input_row_1, 
        html.Br(),
        input_row_2,
        html.Br(), 
        input_row_3,
        html.Br(),
        input_row_4,
        html.Br(),
        submit_button,
        html.Hr(), 
        output_row, 
        html.Br(), 
        html.Hr(), 
        footer
    ])
    
    return layout

# Code to run the home page 
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.UNITED])
app.layout = ACR_Prediction()

###### CALLBACKS #######
@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='operation-result', component_property='value'), 
     Output(component_id='acr-forecast', component_property='value')], 
    [Input('forecast-calls', 'value'),
     Input('vol-var', 'value'),
     Input('fte-count', 'value'),
     Input('forecast-aht', 'value'),
     Input('aht-var', 'value'),
     Input('avail', 'value'),
     Input('idle', 'value'),
     Input('proc-volume', 'value'),
     Input('approval', 'value'),
     Input('cancel', 'value'),
     Input('fcar', 'value'),
     Input('approval-cycle', 'value'),
     Input('overtime', 'value'),
     Input('pend', 'value'),
     Input('ojt', 'value')],
     prevent_initial_call=False 
)
def get_acr_forecast(): 
    return "Success", 3.5
```

Right now, I am returning hard-coded outputs `"Success"` and `3.5` but the final application doesn't show any output. I even added the arguments in the `get_acr_forecast()` but it doesn't work.